# python pandas groupby the unique combination to find the total sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe as below

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [['A','1','US'], ['A','2','US'],['A','1','US'],['B','3','IN'],['B','3','IN'],['C','1','US']]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['System','Number','Country'])
```

I need to find each Country total rows after getting the unique combination of the 'System' and 'Number'

The required output is as below

| Country | count |
| --- | --- |
| US | 3 |
| IN | 1 |

I tried the below to get the unique combination of the 'system' and 'Number' rows but not sure how to get them added to get the above country results

```
df.groupby(['System','Number'])['Country'].nunique()
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
df.drop_duplicates(['System', 'Number']).groupby('Country').agg(Count = ('Country','count')).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical use case for [df.value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html):

```py
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['System', 'Number']).value_counts('Country')
```

Answer (score 0):

df.drop_duplicates().groupby('Country')[['Country']].count()